# Catboost iteration results meaning

Tags: logging, output, catboost

I am fitting CatBoostClassifier like this:

```
clf = CatBoostClassifier(cat_features=cols_cat, random_seed=11, verbose=50)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)


Learning rate set to 0.132799
0:  learn: 0.5495892    total: 296ms    remaining: 4m 55s
50: learn: 0.2028138    total: 14.3s    remaining: 4m 26s
100:    learn: 0.1988373    total: 30.1s    remaining: 4m 28s
150:    learn: 0.1965709    total: 46.2s    remaining: 4m 19s
200:    learn: 0.1949843    total: 1m 2s    remaining: 4m 8s
250:    learn: 0.1938470    total: 1m 18s   remaining: 3m 55s
300:    learn: 0.1928074    total: 1m 35s   remaining: 3m 41s
...
```

What is learn value in the output? 
Why it is decreasing with iterations?
If learn value is saturated and no more decreasing, does this mean that Catboost reached it's optimum?